# System.StringException Invalid Id

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soap, contentversion

I'm getting this error in APEX class which converts CSV file into records. I'm sorry for bad editing of this question but I turned problem liner into quotes.

Example of the data that causes the error:
[image]

Error in console:
[image]

All fields are text fields.

**sensorDatatable.js**

import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

```
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import csvFileRead from '@salesforce/apex/UploadController.csvFileRead';

export default class SensorsDatatable extends LightningElement {

columnsAccount = [
    { label: 'Assigned Base Station', fieldName: 'Base_Station__c', type: 'text'},
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status__c', type: 'url', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Sesnor Model', fieldName: 'Sensor_Model__c', type: 'text' }
];

@api recordId;
@track error;
@track data;


get acceptedCSVFormats() {
    return ['.csv'];
}

uploadFileHandler(event) {
    // Get the list of records from the uploaded files
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;

    // calling apex class csvFileread method
```

> csvFileRead({contentDocumentId : uploadedFiles[0].documentId})

```
    .then(result => {
         window.console.log('result ===> '+result);
         this.data = result;
         this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success!!',
                    message: 'Accounts are created according to the CSV file upload!!!',
                    variant: 'Success',
              }),
         );
    })
    .catch(error => {
         this.error = error;
         console.log(this.error);
         this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error Here!',
                    message: JSON.stringify(error),
                    variant: 'error',
              }),
         );     
    })

 }
}
```

**UploadController.cls**

```
public with sharing class UploadController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Sensor__c> csvFileRead(String contentDocumentId){
    List<Sensor__c> accountInsertList = new List<Sensor__c>();
    Id testId = Id.valueOf(contentDocumentId);
    if(contentDocumentId != null) {
        
        // Fetch File Data based on the basic of document id
```

> ContentVersion contentVersionObj = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM
> ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :testId];

```
        // split the file data
        List<String> csvRecordsList = contentVersionObj.VersionData.toString().split('\n');

        for(Integer i = 1; i < csvRecordsList.size(); i++){
            Sensor__c sensorObj = new Sensor__c();
            List<String> csvRowData = csvRecordsList[i].split(',');
            System.debug('csvRowData====> '+csvRowData);
            sensorObj.Base_Station__c = csvRowData[0]; // accName
            sensorObj.Status__c = csvRowData[1];
            sensorObj.Sensor_Model__c = csvRowData[2];
            accountInsertList.add(sensorObj);
        }

        try{    
            if(!accountInsertList.isEmpty()) {
                insert accountInsertList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
    return accountInsertList;    
}
```

}

Comment: There is not enough information here to identify the problem. Please [edit] to share the data type of each field and an example of the data that causes the error.

Comment: Also note that your CSV parser is a long way from being [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) compliant and will break on a wide variety of CSV data. Consider parsing on the front end with PapaParse and calling Apex only with parsed data.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for the advice! I added additional information

Comment: What does that error message mean to you? The problem is very clear in your error message.

Comment: Are either of `Base_Station__c ` or `Base_Station__c`, lookups or master detail in salesforce? Or they are plain text?

Comment: are you sure that apex method `csvFileRead` is passed a valid ContentDocumentID?

Comment: @NickCook When I googled this error the most common reason was using a string passed from js file as ID

Comment: @NagendraSingh Base_Station__c is lookup field with Base__Station_c object

Comment: @cropredy looks like valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out `Base_Station__c` is a lookup, and you are trying to push a String value = `csvRowData[0]` which is just a string, thus it fails.

You need to query the data first and fetch the ID for the field and populate the ID there.